# Messages behavior after fork()

Tags: c, unix, ipc, message-queue

I'm learning interprocess communication through messages.

In the following code snippet, I apply `fork()` and send messages between the parent and the child processes.

I expect "1 - 2 - 3 - 4" console output. However, I got "1 - 2", and after this, the program seems to be stuck forever on the `msgrcv` line before printing "3". Could anyone tell what's wrong with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 16
#define MSG_KEY1 75
#define MSG_KEY2 76

struct msgform
{
    long     mtype;
    char     mbuf[BUF_SIZE];
    long     mind;
} msg;

struct msgping
{
    long     mtype;
    long     ping ;
} msgPing;

int main() {

    if(fork() == 0) {
    // child process
    int msgid1;
    int msgid2;
    msgid1 = msgget(MSG_KEY1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    msgid2 = msgget(MSG_KEY2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    msg.mtype = 1;
    msgPing.mtype = 1;

    printf("1 - started, sending msgPing\n");

    msgsnd(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 0);

    msgrcv(msgid2, &msg, sizeof(msg), 1, 0);

    printf("3 - msg received, sending msgPing\n");

    msgsnd(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 0);

    msgctl(msgid1, IPC_RMID, 0);
    msgctl(msgid2, IPC_RMID, 0);

    return 0;
    }

    //parent process
    sleep(1);
    int msgid1;
    int msgid2;
    msgid1 = msgget(MSG_KEY1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    msgid2 = msgget(MSG_KEY2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    msgrcv(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 1, 0);

    printf("2 - msgPing received, sending msg\n");

    msgsnd(msgid2, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

    msgrcv(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 1, 0);

    printf("4 - msgPing received, finished\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only set `mtype` in the child but *not* in the parent.

Also, the `msgctl` calls in the child are *racing* against the final `msgrcv` in the parent. That is, the child may complete the `msgctl` call *before* the parent has a chance to complete its final `msgrcv`.

And, I think, the child's `return 0;` should be `exit(0);` to prevent fall through into the parent code.

---

In the refactored code below, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old/broken vs new/fixed code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

---

Here is the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#if 1
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#endif

#define BUF_SIZE 16
#define MSG_KEY1 75
#define MSG_KEY2 76

struct msgform {
    long mtype;
    char mbuf[BUF_SIZE];
    long mind;
} msg;

struct msgping {
    long mtype;
    long ping;
} msgPing;

#define ONERR(_fd) \
    do { \
        if (_fd >= 0) \
            break; \
        printf("msgget error " #_fd " at line %d cldpid=%d -- %s\n", \
            __LINE__,cldpid,strerror(errno)); \
        exit(1); \
    } while (0)

int
main()
{

#if 0
    if (fork() == 0) {
#else
    pid_t cldpid = fork();
    if (cldpid == 0) {
#endif
        // child process
        int msgid1;
        int msgid2;

        msgid1 = msgget(MSG_KEY1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        ONERR(msgid1);
        msgid2 = msgget(MSG_KEY2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        ONERR(msgid2);
        msg.mtype = 1;
        msgPing.mtype = 1;

        printf("1 - started, sending msgPing\n");

        msgsnd(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 0);

        msgrcv(msgid2, &msg, sizeof(msg), 1, 0);
        printf("3 - msg received, sending msgPing\n");

        msgsnd(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 0);

#if 0
        msgctl(msgid1, IPC_RMID, 0);
        msgctl(msgid2, IPC_RMID, 0);
#endif

#if 0
        return 0;
#else
        exit(0);
#endif
    }

    // parent process
    sleep(1);
    int msgid1;
    int msgid2;

    msgid1 = msgget(MSG_KEY1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    ONERR(msgid1);
    msgid2 = msgget(MSG_KEY2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    ONERR(msgid2);

// NOTE/FIX: the parent needs to set this as well as the child
#if 1
    msg.mtype = 1;
    msgPing.mtype = 1;
#endif

    msgrcv(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 1, 0);

    printf("2 - msgPing received, sending msg\n");

    msgsnd(msgid2, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

    msgrcv(msgid1, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 1, 0);

    printf("4 - msgPing received, finished\n");

#if 1
    waitpid(cldpid,NULL,0);

    msgctl(msgid1, IPC_RMID, 0);
    msgctl(msgid2, IPC_RMID, 0);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

When I've done `msgsnd/msgrcv` for realtime, mission critical, production code, I've used a *single* `msgid` for both directions, using a *different* `mtype` value (e.g. `mtype = 1` for parent and `mtype = 2` for the ping).

Here is a further cleaned up and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#if 1
#include <sys/wait.h>
#endif

#define BUF_SIZE 16
#define MSG_KEY1 75
#define MSG_KEY2 76

struct msgform {
    long mtype;
    char mbuf[BUF_SIZE];
    long mind;
} msg;

struct msgping {
    long mtype;
    long ping;
} msgPing;

enum {
    MSGTYPE = 1,
    MSGPING = 2,
};

int
main(void)
{

    int msgid = msgget(MSG_KEY1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

    pid_t cldpid = fork();

    msg.mtype = MSGTYPE;
    msgPing.mtype = MSGPING;

    if (cldpid == 0) {
        sleep(1);

        printf("1 - started, sending msgPing\n");
        msgsnd(msgid, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 0);

        msgrcv(msgid, &msg, sizeof(msg), MSGTYPE, 0);

        printf("3 - msg received, sending msgPing\n");
        msgsnd(msgid, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), 0);

        exit(0);
    }

    // parent process
    sleep(1);

    msgrcv(msgid, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), MSGPING, 0);
    printf("2 - msgPing received, sending msg\n");

    msgsnd(msgid, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

    msgrcv(msgid, &msgPing, sizeof(msgPing), MSGPING, 0);
    printf("4 - msgPing received, finished\n");

    waitpid(cldpid,NULL,0);
    msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the message type initialization here:

```
msg.mtype = 1;
msgPing.mtype = 1;
```

These values are only getting initialized in the child. When the parent tries to send a message in `msg`, the `mtype` hasn't been set, so the child waits endlessly for a message of `mtype` `1`, which never arrives.

Either setting those two values before `fork()`, or setting them in the parent as well as the child, makes this work:

```
$ ./msg
1 - started, sending msgPing
3 - msg received, sending msgPing
2 - msgPing received, sending msg
4 - msgPing received, finished
```

in about a second.